# Which team yields highest CP - strongest Pokemon

Tags: pokemon-go

Between Valor and Mystic which team will yield the highest CP Pokemon?

It seems that Mystic will get a bonus after evolving a Pokemon. And Valor gets a bonus while "training" that Pokemon, but which of the two will result in the stronger Pokemon?

Comment: my understanding is that the team choice is entirely cosmetic; there are no team bonuses.

Comment: @KutuluMike Any proof of this?

Comment: Why don't you provide proof of what you're saying?

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer I am not saying anything, I am asking. :)

Comment: The premise of your post is unproven. If you could point us to a source, that'd be a great help for everyone who's been wondering the same thing.

Answer (score 3):

Similar to its predecessor (ingress) team selection is only for competitive mechanics and cosmetic purposes.

Therefore, the team that yields the strongest CP Pokemon will be whichever one has a player that has the best luck.

No differences between the teams has been shown or confirmed to my knowledge.